# Finding roots of an equation involving a summation using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math

I am currently to new to sympy and I am trying to reproduce the Mathematica example in the attached image in Python. My attempt is written below but it returns an empty list[image]

```
import sympy


m , n, D_star, a, j =  sympy.symbols('m , n, D_star, a, j')

s1 = sympy.Sum(a**(j-1),(j, 1, m-1))

rhs = 6 * sympy.sqrt((D_star * (1 + a)*(n - 1))/2)

expand_expr = sympy.solve(s1 - rhs, m) 

temp = sympy.lambdify((a, n, D_star), expand_expr, 'numpy')

n = 100
a = 1.2
D_star = 2.0

ms = temp(1.2, 100, 2.0)
ms

# what I get is an empty list []

# expected answer using Mma FindRoot function is 17.0652
```

Comment: In your problem, `m` can take only integer values. If so, what do you mean by finding the root to be `17.0652`? `17.0652` is not an integer. So, how to interpret the summation when `m` happens to be a non-integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `.doit()` to expand the sum seems to help. It gives `Piecewise((m - 1, Eq(a, 1)), ((a - a**m)/(1 - a), True))/a` for the sum in `s1`.

```py
from sympy import symbols, Eq, Sum, sqrt, solve, lambdify

m, n, j, a, D_star = symbols('m n j a D_star')

s1 = Sum(a**(j - 1), (j, 1, m - 1)).doit()

rhs = 6 * sqrt((D_star * (1 + a) * (n - 1)) / 2)

expand_expr = solve(Eq(s1, rhs), m)

temp = lambdify((a, n, D_star), expand_expr, 'numpy')

n = 100
a = 1.2
D_star = 2.0

ms = temp(1.2, 100, 2.0)
```

This gives for `expand_expr`:

```
[Piecewise((log(a*(3*sqrt(2)*a*sqrt(D_star*(a*n - a + n - 1)) - 3*sqrt(2)*sqrt(D_star*(a*n - a + n - 1)) + 1))/log(a), Ne(a, 1)), (nan, True)),
 Piecewise((3*sqrt(2)*a*sqrt(D_star*(a*n - a + n - 1)) + 1, Eq(a, 1)), (nan, True))]
```

which separates into `a != 1` and `a == 1`.

The result of `ms` gives `[array(17.06524172), array(nan)]`, again in a bit awkward way to separate a hypothetical `a == 1`.

Comment: Exactly the .doit() was the missing part.